# how to make code on front end log in or not login

Tags: reactjs, frontend, backend

I don't get error messages, but when I log in it don't mater if I get the password right or wrong it logs in anyway.  How do I make it not log in if I get the hashed Password wrong?, here is my code...

```
handleLogIn = async () => {
const { userName, password } = this.state.user;
const { users } = this.state;

await postFetch(`/users/login`, {
  userName: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).userName,
  password: password,
  hashPass: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).password
})
  .then(
    this.setState({
      user: {
        ...this.state.user,
        id: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).id,
        firstName: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName)
          .firstName,
        lastName: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).lastName,
        userName: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).userName,
        password: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).password,
        email: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).email,
      },
    }),
    this.getPreference(users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).id),
    this.getReadings(users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).id)
  )
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

When I pass this to the back end I get one of three messages back in json format

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what is the response structure when the password is wrong, but either way you have to change `then` handler and check the result.

This is how I would do it:

```js
await postFetch(`/users/login`, {
  userName: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).userName,
  password: password,
  hashPass: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).password
})
  .then(result => {

   // handle wrong password
   if(!result.success)  {
    console.log(result.errors)
    return;
   }

    this.setState({
      user: {
        ...this.state.user,
        id: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).id,
        firstName: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName)
          .firstName,
        lastName: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).lastName,
        userName: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).userName,
        password: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).password,
        email: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).email,
      },
    });
    this.getPreference(users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).id);
    this.getReadings(users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).id);
    }
  )
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

Comment: that worked but  if I get it right it doesn't show the data i'm looking for...

Comment: Whats the response structure? I provided here an example of how response can look like i.e `{success, errors}`

Comment: in the console it gives me undefined

Comment: it gives a 400 Bad Request and then undefined

Comment: Hmm get rid of `  if(!result.success)  {` if statement and make sure the code `this.setState({` is still inside function `.then(result => {`

Comment: it gets in no matter what and if I get it wrong it puts a 400 err

Comment: any other ideas?